# Securing Kubernetes Dashboard with ABAC

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard, readonly, abac

I have Kubernetes Dashboard installed with basic auth using ABAC. Is there a way to make a user/group that can readonly when logged into the dashboard? Currently, if I skip the login screen (not logged in), I can still view and modify the cluster inside dashboard. Adding "readonly":true to the system:authenticated line doesn't seem to do anything.

I have a policy file:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1",
  "kind": "Policy",
  "spec": {
    "user": "admin",
    "namespace": "*",
    "resource": "*",
    "apiGroup": "*"
  }
}
{
  "apiVersion": "abac.authorization.kubernetes.io/v1beta1",
  "kind": "Policy",
  "spec": {
    "group": "system:authenticated",
    "nonResourcePath": "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into external frameworks like opa or axiomatics?

Comment: I think this Github [issue #2668](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2668) might be what you are talking about.

Comment: @DavidBrossard I have a restriction and cannot use external frameworks

Comment: @Crou Thanks for the link, it gives me a hint, but the original poster is using abac AND rbac, I'm only using abac.